# how to keep tab indent even after uncomment in visual studio 2017?

Tags: tabs, formatting, indentation

I am very new to VS 2017.
I used VS 2013 for ages, and I am very used to it.
But several days ago, I upgraded to 2017 and I found a serious problem of IDE.

My C# Text Editor's indenting option looks like below.
Block, tab 4 size, indent 4 size, keep tabs.

[image]

When I comment any lines, it keeps my indent.
But when I uncomment, it goes like it ignores the indent.
Like below.

[image]

When normal, it keeps my indent as tab.

[image]

When commented, it still keeps my indent as tab.

[image]

When uncommented, the indent disappears and turns into a space.

Anyone knows what I have to check the other options?